# Concatenating props within Inline CSS (React)

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I'm currently trying to use props within my inline CSS. I'm curious to know why can't I concatenate *this.props.color* when using *linear-gradient* on the *background-image property*. Is there possibly another way I could go about achieving this or am I missing something?

```
render() { 
    let background = {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        position: "fixed",
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(to right," + this.props.color + "0%, #0072ff 100%)"
    };
    return (
        <div style={background}></div>
      );
}
```

Component in use:

```
     <Background color='red'/>
```

Comment: what is `red0%` supposed to mean?

Comment: Oh my God...the space. Thank you!

Comment: do yourself a favor, use template strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a space before `0%`

Do like the following:

```
render() { 
    let background = {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        position: "fixed",
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to right,${this.props.color} 0%, #0072ff 100%)`
    };
    return (
        <div style={background}></div>
      );
}
```